# Error after upgrading from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2.2

Tags: upgrade

I updated my Magento 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2.2 via the magento downloader.
I got this error report after i logged in.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:731:"SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`visibility`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`url_path`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`cost`, `e`.`is_recurring`, `e`.`recurring_profile`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`gift_message_available`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`sku_type`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_title` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` WHERE (e.status = 1) AND (e.entity_id IN(8430, 8431, 8432, 8433, 8430, 8431, 8432, 8433))

";i:1;s:7824:"#0 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.`ent...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.`ent...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `e`.`ent...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(740): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `e`.`ent...', Array)
#7 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1045): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `e`.`ent...')
#8 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(871): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
#9 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
#10 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php(1495): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
#11 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Item/Collection.php(182): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection->addOptionsToResult()
#12 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Item/Collection.php(139): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection->_assignProducts()
#13 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(587): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection->_afterLoad()
#14 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#15 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1697): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
#16 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1396): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->isVirtual()
#17 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php(222): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->getTotals()
#18 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Abstract.php(179): Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar->getTotalsCache()
#19 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php(92): Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Abstract->getTotals()
#20 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml(41): Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar->getSubtotal()
#21 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/d...')
#22 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
#23 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#24 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#26 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('minicart_conten...', true)
#27 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/minicart.phtml(50): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('minicart_conten...')
#28 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/d...')
#29 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
#30 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#31 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#32 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#33 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('minicart_head', true)
#34 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/header.phtml(168): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('minicart_head')
#35 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/d...')
#36 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
#37 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#38 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#39 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#40 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
#41 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/1column.phtml(49): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
#42 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/d...')
#43 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
#44 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#45 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#46 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#47 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#48 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#49 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#50 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#51 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#52 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#53 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#54 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#55 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#56 /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#57 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Can you give me any advice what i have to do ?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try clearing cache and removing your locks folders from the var directory? How about indexing at the command line?

Comment: The cache was not even enabled. I cleared cache and the problem is still there. I do not know how to index the command line..

Answer (score 1):

Please check and edit the products which id's are 8430, 8431, 8432, 8433, 8430, 8431, 8432, 8433. have to check all fields and fill with correct details.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system -> catalog -> Use Flat Catalog Category and check this value,  if it's set to yes, temporarily set it to "No" This being set to yes is enabling Flat Tables which is part of your error. This may solve your problem.

I don't know what level of system access you have Mysql , Command line so I'm going to see if I can help you without doing that.  Also take note, I rarely do upgrades from connect, too buggy unless the Magento code is completely stock

If this value is set to no, I have a few other ideas.

Comment: Value is set to no, can you help me out further ?